# How do I rig flip flop sandals correctly?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I'm working on an advanced rig for a character wearing flip flops. I'm trying to get the rig right and is almost perfect. The only flaw is that when you turn all the foot bones at 90°, the weight painting gets screwy. I think it may have something to do with the weight painting I did using vertex groups, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I **refuse** to go without it.
Please help.

PS: I feel like the weight painting is too smooth and I wonder if it's possible to sharpen it. Blender Guru did it before in a towel tutorial and someone did ask about it on another site *(I forget which)*, but it said when I don't have subdivision surface it'll work tried it and it didn't. I just want to know if anyone can help.

[image]

File: [flip_flop_physics.blend](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1U3F6W2ZU7fR_RvJ8gCZ2smjAHKtXwlSu)

I'm using 2.83.1 by the way.

[image]

Also the bones *(the ones that are away from the skeleton)* on the outside don't affect the sandal... *I think*.

Comment: Please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182360/edit) to your question. Other users should not have to rely on downloading a file to understand your question.

Comment: Can someone please help? I still can't figure this out. I don't know what to do and like I said, I refuse to go without.